# Why does this cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++

Why does this cause a segmentation fault?

```
int compareFiles(const char* outFile, const char* expectedFile) {
    int N = 10000;
    FILE* f1;
    FILE* f2;
    char buf1[N];
    char buf2[N];

    f1 = fopen(expectedFile, "r");
    f2 = fopen(outFile, "r");

    do {
        size_t r1 = fread(buf1, 1, N, f1);
        size_t r2 = fread(buf2, 1, N, f2);

        if (r1 != r2 ||
            memcmp(buf1, buf2, r1)) {
          return 0;
        }
    } while (!feof(f1) || !feof(f2));

    return feof(f1) && feof(f2);
}
```

Comment: *Where* does the crash  happen? Have you tried running in a debugger?

Comment: You assume the open is successful and that all reads are successful. You also have a VLA, which is non-standard, and you might as well use `std::ifstream` if using C++.

Comment: Also, you might want to change that loop condition. Right now if e.g. `f1` is at the end but `f2` is not, the loop will continue.

Comment: You might have more luck if you tag this C.

Comment: In summary, you need some error checking.

Comment: how do you call the function?

Comment: So @RyanSmith Do you want to use `C++` or do you prefer `C` as the code suggests?

Comment: C++ I just want to compare two files. Why is this so hard in this language. I honestly just want to bang my head on the table.

Comment: @hyde I am doing C++ not C hence why I tagged C++ and not C.

Comment: @RyanSmith that is very C-like C++, and your complaint seems to be about C being hard. I think it would be easier if you actually used C++ standard library ;)

Comment: @RyanSmith, but the code you posted is C, not C++.

Comment: Well I want to compare two files in C++ not C.

Comment: @RyanSmith to avoid confusion, you should at least `#include <cstdio>` and then use `std::fopen`. That way people don't get caught up with your C++ looking exactly like C... Also, don't use VLA in C++ (non-constant size for an array, `N` in your code).

Comment: @hyde I just realised that, apologies.

Comment: I have this working now, thanks to everyone that tried to help. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check return value from fopen - if NULL is returned you will get a seg fault on subsequent file operations.

Answer (score -3):

Your code is perfectly correct and it's working in my machine. In this case, Segmentation will come only when it does not have the input file to read.

Comment: Those downvotes are probably, because any code, which does not check for errors with file operations, is not "perfectly correct" by any definition of "perfect" or "correct"...